# Are there any scripts for processing multiple RADseq plates with redundant barcodes?

Tags: barcode, fastq

I am conducting ipyrad analyses on 3 plates of RADseq data but the barcodes are redundant (each plate reuses the same set of 96 barcodes). I was hoping to analyze all 3 plates together but am uncertain about how I can do this in ipyrad. Or whether it is necessary to add additional barcodes to obtain 288 unique left+right barcodes for the 288 samples.

Fastq sequence identifier:
@MG01HX02:1030:HCTKYCCX2:8:1101:8410:1432 1:N:0:NTAACGAC+NCTATACC

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has a similar question, I learned how to do this.
Run ipyrad step 1 for each plate separately to assign the unique ID based on the correct barcode file. Ensure that all of these outputs are in the same folder. Re-run ipyrad from step one (through 7) but reference this folder of fastqs rather than the initial fastq files.